# How to get interactive input from user and to be able to use arrowkeys while entering input?

Tags: python

When I do a raw_input() and enter values, I am not able to use my arrow-keys to change stuff... is there any way for doing that?

Thanx readline module helps in line editing features. How to use the readline module?
Just importing the readline module works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `raw_input()` works. It reads a line from the prompt, and then processes it after the newline character.

The docs are pretty clear:
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input

If you try to throw arrow keys into the mix, your terminal is likely to add those characters to the returned string. Then again, it may not, depending on your operating system. Don't count on it.

Perhaps you want the `readline` module?

http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#module-readline

Comment: Read the _Fine_ documentation I linked in my answer?

Comment: `raw_input()` was renamed `input()` in Python 3+ (and needs no import). [Simple docs here](http://sweetme.at/2014/01/22/how-to-get-user-input-from-the-command-line-in-a-python-script/)

Comment: @Chris you still need the import to be able to use arrow keys

Answer (score 11):

Try loading the readline module (import readline). That will make things work for you.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for examples, there's a nice introduction to the readline module here:
https://pymotw.com/2/readline/